How can I make Tensorflow 2.9.1 compatible with CUDA 12.4?
I have a .py training script using tensorflow==2.9.1 which successfully runs on my local CPU.I need to use this specific tensorflow version since I have some rust code using tflite for model inference which only supports tf versions up to 2.9.1
Now I want to use my universities GPU-cluster which has CUDA 12.4 installed for model training (obviously, I don't have privileges to downgrade CUDA on that GPU).
Once I'm testing if tensorflow is able to access the GPU via python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))" I get 2024-08-28 15:46:24.327910: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
I already read that cudnn should be installed accordingly. But going though the dependency tables here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#install_gpu_support_optional, I see that my tensorflow version is only compatible with CUDA 11.
how can I run my code using tensorflow==2.9.1 on a CUDA 12.4 supported GPU?
I tried to install the following packages to enable GPU access:
nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.3.4.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.3.101
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12==12.3.107
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.3.107
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.3.101
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.7.29
nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.12.1
nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.4.107
nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.5.4.101
nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.2.0.103
nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12==12.3.101

Still I'm getting 2024-08-28 15:46:24.327910: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
when executing python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

it seems like it but I need to ask: Are you on Linux? Or if on Windows, do you use Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) ? Just don't use newer versions of Tensorflow with Windows if you want to use a GPU.

Straightforwardly, you can’t . Offical  Tensorflow 2.9 builds require CUDA 11.2 and CUDNN 8.1 for CUDA 11.2. This is a non-negotiable system requirement

okay, thanks for your answer.

@FlorianFasmeyer I'm on linux, yes.
